# trying to add Guest through google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-apps

Am trying to add a Guest to the calendar through google apps script that takes a calendar request from the user through Google forms---> it then updates a Google online excel sheet if no conflicts and makes the reservation if no conflict all this works fine but if the user tries to edit the time for the reservation they can't as they aren't the owner of the calendar to make edits so the only workaround I could think of is adding there email from the submitted request and add them as guest to that specific event but it ended unsuccessfully.

1. user submits a google form request with his email name time etc.
2. google forms update google excel sheet and checks that there are no conflicts.
3. updates the calendar successfully and sends a confirmation to the user's email.
4. The user needs to edit the time of his reservation on the calendar but can't as he is not a guest and can't edit the calendar (trying to solve this by automatically adding him as a guest to the requested event.

read so solutions here on adding location but was unsuccessful in adding the user as a guest.

tried adding

```
var body = {
  'sendNotification': true,
  'attendees': attendees
};

var ret = Calendar.Events.patch(body, calendarId, eventId);
```

but was unsuccessful

Code looks like:

```
// Room Reservation

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

// Calendar to output reservations to
var cal145 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('xxxxxx@resource.calendar.google.com');

// Create use data from user submission
// This function submits data from the google form and inputs it into the "Room Reservation" sheet by the user
function Submission(){
  var row = lastRow;
  this.timestamp = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
  this.NameReason = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  this.email = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
  this.date = sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
  this.time = sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue();
  this.duration = sheet.getRange(row, 7).getValue();
  this.room = sheet.getRange(row, 8).getValue();
  // Info not from spreadsheet
  this.roomInt = this.room.replace(/\D+/g, '');
  this.status;
  this.dateString = (this.date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + this.date.getDate() + '/' + this.date.getYear();
  this.timeString = this.time.toLocaleTimeString();
  this.date.setHours(this.time.getHours());
  this.date.setMinutes(this.time.getMinutes());
  this.calendar = eval('cal' + String(this.roomInt));
  return this;
}

// Use duration to create endTime variable
function getEndTime(request){
  request.endTime = new Date(request.date);
  switch (request.duration){
    case "1 hour":
      request.endTime.setMinutes(request.date.getMinutes() + 60);
      request.endTimeString = request.endTime.toLocaleTimeString();
      break;
    case "2 hours":
      request.endTime.setMinutes(request.date.getMinutes() + 120);
      request.endTimeString = request.endTime.toLocaleTimeString();
      break;
    case "3 hours":
      request.endTime.setMinutes(request.date.getMinutes() + 180);
      request.endTimeString = request.endTime.toLocaleTimeString();
      break;
  }
}

// Check for appointment conflicts
function getConflicts(request){
  var conflicts = request.calendar.getEvents(request.date, request.endTime);
  if (conflicts.length < 1) {
    request.status = "Approve";

  } else {
    request.status = "Conflict";
  }

}

function draftEmail(request){
  request.buttonLink = "xxxxxxx ";
  request.buttonText = "New Request";
  switch (request.status) {
    case "Approve":
      request.subject = "Confirmation: " + request.room + " Reservation for " + request.dateString;
      request.header = "Confirmation";
      request.message = "Your room reservation has been scheduled.";
      break;
    case "Conflict":
      request.subject = "Conflict with " + request.room + "Reservation for " + request.dateString;
      request.header = "Conflict";
      request.message = "There is a scheduling conflict. Please pick another time."
      request.buttonText = "Reschedule";
      break;
  }
}

function updateCalendar(request){
  var event = request.calendar.createEvent(
    request.NameReason,
    request.date,
    //request.reason,
    request.endTime
    )
}

function sendEmail(request){
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: request.email,
    subject: request.header,
    htmlBody: makeEmail(request)
  })
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn).setValue("Sent: " + request.status);
}



function sendinvite(request)
{


  request.addGuest(email);


}

// --------------- main --------------------

function main(){
  var request = new Submission();
  getEndTime(request);
  getConflicts(request);
  draftEmail(request);
  Logger.log(request);
  sendEmail(request);
  if (request.status == "Approve") updateCalendar(request);
  if (request.status == "Approve")
  {
   sendinvite(request);
  }
}
```

The final result should let the user edit the time of the event created although he is not the owner of the calendar. the function should add the user as a guest to that specific event he requested so he could edit the time.

this script works fine currently as is without the addition of guest sendinvite function.

thanks

Comment: @Cooper you are correct about the lastRow but this reservation system isn't very dynamic in regards to the number of reservations made but well observed. As for the sharing, I wouldn't want to share it with everyone. the add guest should be good enough as once that user is added as a guest to that event created on the calendar the guest can edit the time. [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#addGuest(String))

Comment: @Serg-insas any idea